# Forwarded emails should be considered invalid

Tags: c#

We have this requirement where we send an email to a user where he can click yes or no. Based on the click some action would take place. But if the user forwards it to someone, and if they click on the buttons nothing should happen.

One way to make this happen is to have the recipient of the email to sign in, before he can click. But ideally, we would like to avoid that.

How can this be done if we don't want the user to sign in?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://litmus.com/blog/preventing-unsubscribes-in-forwarded-emails) for some ideas on how to handle forwarded emails.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bona-fide e-mail that arrives in someone's gmail inbox or something, I'm assuming?  If that's the case, you are going to have to authenticate them one way or another using your system.

Some kind of HTML-format email with image/links on it to direct to your site, the links including some kind of unique-key that you can use to look up the user who received the e-mail with said unique-key, prepopulating the user ID field, and them having to supply their password to authenticate.

That's about the only way I can imagine it working, unless you are relying on the user having some kind of third-party identity-verification service like uh... what's the Microsoft one called, Passport?  I'm very unfamiliar with that.